# Sql date range with amount

Tags: sql

I would like to arrange the data in account statement format, but I totally no idea to write the SQL commands, especially range of dates.

Table A

```
Creditors name       Invoice No         Due date          Outstanding Amt
Company A            A001              1/8/2014            1500
Company B            A002              1/6/2014             300
Company B            A003              1/7/2014             900
Company B            A004              5/7/2014              50        
Company c            A005              31/12/2014           200
```

Result, Statement Date: 11/8/14

```
Creditors name    0-30 Days    31-60 Days   61-90 Days   Over 90 Days   Amt Due        
Company A          1500           0           0              0           1500
Company B             0           950          300            0           1250
Company c             0            0           0             200           200
```

Please help & Thank you

Comment: What is the question? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the records with below mentioned query.

```
SELECT *
FROM periods
WHERE range_start <= @check_period_end
      AND range_end >= @check_period_start
```

P.S. Update @check_period_end & @check_period_start with the relevant start and end date in single quote.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the period as in your example by this query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05')
```

Now if you want to make output table like in your example by single query only it would be too much complex.First try to use the views with the above query and then fetch data...Try this and if you gets any error then ask here..At least try first..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure ... I thought this statement works (not tested)

```
SELECT T01.[Creditors name],
(SELECT SUM() FROM TABLEA T02 WHERE DATEDIFF(day,T02.[Due date], GetDate())) BETWEEN -1 AND 31 AND T01.[Creditors name] = T02.[Creditors name])  AS [0-30 Days],
(SELECT SUM() FROM TABLEA T03 WHERE DATEDIFF(day,T02.[Due date], GetDate())) BETWEEN -30 AND 61 AND T01.[Creditors name] = T03.[Creditors name]) AS [31-60 Days],
(SELECT SUM() FROM TABLEA T04 WHERE DATEDIFF(day,T02.[Due date], GetDate())) BETWEEN -60 AND 91 AND T01.[Creditors name] = T04.[Creditors name]) AS [61-90 Days],
(SELECT SUM() FROM TABLEA T05 WHERE DATEDIFF(day,T02.[Due date], GetDate())) > 90 AND T01.[Creditors name] = T05.[Creditors name]) AS [Over 90 Days],
SUM(T01.[Outstanding Amt]) AS [Amt Due]
FROM TABLEA T01
GROUP BY T01.[Creditors name]
```